# Rails 7 net-protocol and io-wait dependency

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to deploy a webapp in Ruby 3.0.2 and Rails 7.0.1 and I have a problem after deploying it via capistrano in a production server Ubuntu 20.04 with nginx(1.18.0) and passenger(6.0.12).

All the processes work fine but the app can not start in production. I get the passenger error page. Finding in logs I get the next error:

**"Error: The application encountered the following error: You have already activated io-wait 0.1.0, but your Gemfile requires io-wait 0.2.1. Since io-wait is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports io-wait as a default gem"**

I have tried to remove the gem io-wait but is a default system gem and I cannot remove it, I have upgraded the bundler to the latest (2.3.4) and the error persists. I have added the latest io-wait version (0.2.1) and got the same error.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I too have just hit this issue.  Hoping someone can help us both out soon!

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by adding

```rb
gem "io-wait", "0.1.0"
```

I then also had the problem with "strscan". Had to downgrade to "3.0.0".

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get things going by using the following:
gem "io-wait", "0.2.0"

Answer (score 2):

In my gem file I set the two offending gems to the old versions.

```rb
gem "io-wait", "0.1.0"
gem "strscan", "3.0.0"
```

After that, deploying and booting the app worked fine.

Ruby v3.0.2
Rails 7.0.0